# Why doesn't dissolve finish? It just stops without error message

Tags: qgis, dissolve

I have a shapefile of the whole UK that contained Postcode area, district, and full postcode.

I was going to try and dissolve the regions into separate business areas by joining a lookup table that identified, for each postcode which business area it's assigned to. But I couldn't get the business area to appear in the dissolve popup window.

So instead I modified the DBF file, adding the new business area field. Now when I go into the dissolve function, the dissolve field does appear there but I can't get it to successfully finish. It just stops. No error messages. Nothing.

I think what I'm trying to do is simple but QGIS just doesn't seem to be happy.

This is the very first thing I'm trying to do with QGIS so please be patient with me.

Comment: Dissolve your sector (full postcode) with your Business areas, but you will need to check the format of both - they might not match

Comment: The dissolve tool is pretty slow. How big is your dataset (no. features)?

Comment: Can you provide the version of QGIS you are using?

Comment: Hi, this would be better off posted as a comment as it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Is this dataset available for testing?

Comment: Hi - it's 1.8.0 and i'm trying to dissolve actual postcodes, so 1.6million of them for uk wide into 16 regions. With a colleagues help, i've this morning joined the source vector to a lookup table, saved it as a new shapefile, and then the joined fields appear in the table attributes. The dissolve is now chugging along, but has taken around 2 hours to do 2%, but i'ts only a 1.8ghz pentium with 2gb ram running vista so not the fastest machine in the world.

Comment: You need more processor and RAM for that type of task with that dataset.